# Webpack multi-config callback errors and stats

Tags: javascript, node.js, build, webpack

I am trying to use multiple Webpack configs when running in watch mode.

This gist is, the compilation callback is being called with different arguments depending on whether I use `build` or `watch`. I haven't been able to dig up any usages like this, and was wondering if anyone else has seen this behavior.

```
var webpack = require('webpack');

var configs = [config, config]  // let me know if you need this
var done = function () {        // err, stats?
  console.log('args', arguments);
};
```

**Single run mode**
This makes some sense (2 compilations, 2 stats objects), and errors are correctly bubbled up.

```
webpack(configs).run(done);
// args {
//   '0': null,
//   '1':  { 
//     stats: [ [Object], [Object] ],
//     hash: '6939dac42dcc6c751bc6a0de33bd8893f6a13f78'
//   }
// }
```

**Watch mode**
This can even be output multiple times.

```
webpack(configs).watch(done);
// {
//   '0': null,
//   '1': {
//     compilation: {
//       _plugins: [Object],
//       compiler: [Object],
//       resolvers: [Object],
//       ...
//       hash: 'a0de33bd8893f6a13f78',
//       fileDependencies: [Object],
//       contextDependencies: [],
//       missingDependencies: [] },
//     hash: 'a0de33bd8893f6a13f78',
//     startTime: 1439969525156,
//     endTime: 1439969525645
//   }
// }
```

Let me know if you need anymore details.

```
"webpack": "^1.10.5"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the reporting to work again with the following snippet in the `done` handler. Here's a summary of findings when compiling in either mode:

**`run` mode**
This handler only fires once and is passed an array of `stats` under a summary `compilation` object. Simply loop over `compilation.stats` and `.toString(opts)` them.

**`watch` mode**
This handler is fired *once per config* in the initial array of configs. Each invocation is passed the corresponding `stats` object itself which you may directly stringify with `.toString(opts)`.

```
function done(err, compilation) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('[webpack] error:', err);
    return;
  }

  // Stats are populated differently in build vs. watch mode.
  var stats = compilation.stats || [compilation];
  console.log('[webpack] the following asset bundles were built:');
  stats.forEach(function (c) {
    console.log(c.toString(statsOpts));
  });
};
```